# How to separate a list of molecules based on how many hydrogens are attached to a certain atom?

Tags: python, chemistry, rdkit, cheminformatics

I have alkene molecules of formula C9H17B. How can I separate these molecules into three classes, one being the class that has C-B-H2, one that has C2-B-H and one that has C3-B. How would I do this? I've tried using smiles and also as mol but my approaches aren't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find specific substructures use SMARTS.

https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html

If I see it correctly these are the three types of boron you are looking for.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

smiles = ['CCB', 'CCBC', 'CCB(C)(C)']

mols = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(s) for s in smiles]
Draw.MolsToGridImage(mols)
```

[image]

Write SMARTS for boron with three connections `BX3` and number of hydrogen `H2`, `H1`, `H0`.

```
smarts = ['[BX3;H2]', '[BX3;H1]', '[BX3;H0]']
patts = [Chem.MolFromSmarts(s) for s in smarts]
```

Now you can proof for substructure in each molecule.

```
for p in patts:
    for m in mols:
        print(m.HasSubstructMatch(p))
    print()

True
False
False

False
True
False

False
False
True
```

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html#looping-over-atoms-and-bonds

Copied from above link:

Atoms keep track of their neighbors:

```py
>>> atom = m.GetAtomWithIdx(0) # You might need to adjust how you find the atom.
>>> [x.GetAtomicNum() for x in atom.GetNeighbors()]
[8, 6]
```

Then just check how many neighbours are hydrogen atoms.  Hope this works for you.